# How to implement in Analysis services History with StartDate and EndDate

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, ssas

I guess that's a beginner question, but i can't find any solution or best practice even asking google. So here my problem, let's say we've got a fact table with sells, each day we've got some sells (or not) for a vendor. Imagine that we've got another table for the vendor (one dimension of our cube) and that they are linked to a store(oh another dimension). They can change store, so we've got a table who link vendor to store like that for period :

LinkID(surrogate key) StoreID VendorID BeginDate EndDate

The vendor was in the store from the BeginDate to the EndDate.
My question is, what is the best way to model that ? If i want an history for each Store, i have to take care about which vendor was in the store and for how many time. Do i make a Named  Query to create a snapshot fact table (to create a table with SQL statment and finally i'll have a link for each day and each store and each vendor. Like that :
Date StoreID VendorID
Or can i make that with a calculated dimension or another cube who will "link" the history table with vendor and store and the time dimension.
Any help/link or even keyword for google would be appreciate ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called  - Slowly Changing Dimensions

Quick Overview of SCD:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

SCD in SSAS

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/barbaro/archive/2007/09/08/Slowly-Changing-Dimension-type-2-in-SSAS.aspx